# Optimize Group By in LINQ to Entities

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have this query in LINQ to Entities.

```
        var query = (from s in db.ForumStatsSet
                     where s.LogDate >= date1 && s.LogDate <= date2
                     group s by new { s.Topic.topicID, s.Topic.subject, s.Topic.Forum.forumName, s.Topic.datum, s.Topic.Forum.ForumGroup.name, s.Topic.Forum.forumID } into g
                     orderby g.Count() descending
                     select new TopicStatsData
                     {
                         TopicId = g.Key.topicID,
                         Count = g.Count(),
                         Subject = g.Key.subject,
                         ForumGroupName = g.Key.name,
                         ForumName = g.Key.forumName,
                         ForumId = g.Key.forumID
                     });
```

I know it is kind of an "Evil" query but it is only used in a admin interface. But the SQL it generated is absolutely horrifying. Have a look at this baby.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (50) 
[Project6].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project6].[TopicId] AS [TopicId], 
[Project6].[C4] AS [C2], 
[Project6].[subject] AS [subject], 
[Project6].[name] AS [name], 
[Project6].[forumName] AS [forumName], 
[Project6].[C2] AS [C3]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project5].[TopicId] AS [TopicId], 
    [Project5].[subject] AS [subject], 
    [Project5].[forumName] AS [forumName], 
    [Project5].[name] AS [name], 
    1 AS [C1], 
     CAST( [Project5].[forumID] AS int) AS [C2], 
    [Project5].[C1] AS [C3], 
    [Project5].[C2] AS [C4]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project4].[TopicId] AS [TopicId], 
        [Project4].[forumID] AS [forumID], 
        [Project4].[subject] AS [subject], 
        [Project4].[forumName] AS [forumName], 
        [Project4].[name] AS [name], 
        [Project4].[C1] AS [C1], 
        (SELECT 
            COUNT(cast(1 as bit)) AS [A1]
            FROM        [dbo].[tForumStats] AS [Extent14]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tTopic] AS [Extent15] ON [Extent14].[TopicId] = [Extent15].[topicID]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tForum] AS [Extent16] ON [Extent15].[forumID] = [Extent16].[forumID]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tForum] AS [Extent17] ON [Extent15].[forumID] = [Extent17].[forumID]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tForum] AS [Extent18] ON [Extent15].[forumID] = [Extent18].[forumID]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tForumGroup] AS [Extent19] ON [Extent18].[forumGroupID] = [Extent19].[forumGroupID]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tForum] AS [Extent20] ON [Extent15].[forumID] = [Extent20].[forumID]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tForumGroup] AS [Extent21] ON [Extent20].[forumGroupID] = [Extent21].[forumGroupID]
            WHERE ([Extent14].[LogDate] >= @p__linq__25) AND ([Extent14].[LogDate] = @p__linq__25) AND ([Extent6].[LogDate] = @p__linq__25) AND ([Extent1].[LogDate]
```

I do not as anyone to explain that query but it would be great to get some tips on how to optimze the query so that it just do a simple regular join. Something like this works as fine if I write the SQL myself.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfViews, s.topicid AS topicId, t.subject AS TopicSubject, g.[name] AS ForumGroupName, f.forumName AS ForumName 
FROM tForumStats s
join tTopic t on s.topicid = t.topicid
join tForum f on f.forumid = t.forumid
JOIN tForumGroup g ON f.forumGroupID = g.forumGroupID
WHERE s.[LogDate] between @date1 AND @date2
group by s.topicid,  t.subject, f.Forumname, t.Datum, g.[name]
order by count(*) desc
```

Btw, i LOVE this site. Amazing design and usability! Hope it works good to get some help to :)

Comment: Hope, looks like the site cut the large query generated bu Linq to entites, i don't blame you. I think you get the idea ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of joining all tables in group by you can join the given tables by yourself.
Can you try this;

```
from s in db.ForumStatsSet
join t in db.Topics on t.TopicId == s.TopicId
join f in db.Forums on f.ForumId == t.ForumId
join fg in db.ForumGroups on fg.ForumGroupId == f.ForumGroupId
where s.LogDate >= date1 && s.LogDate <= 
group s by new { t.TopicId, t.subject, f.forumName, t.datum, fg.name, f.forumID } into g
orderby g.Count() descending
select new TopicStatsData
{
 TopicId = g.Key.topicID,
 Count = g.Count(),
 Subject = g.Key.subject,
 ForumGroupName = g.Key.name,
 ForumName = g.Key.forumName,
 ForumId = g.Key.forumID
 });
```

ps: There may be some errors, but logically it should be correct!

Comment: Thanks, i can't manage to do a join do. The old LINQ to SQL way where you just add multiple from clauses like 
from s in db.ForumStatsSet
from t in s.Topic

Doesnt work and i do not have any ID's to do the join on since that is "removed" buy the model .. hmm .. im confused ..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the grouping construct. Try extract the data first (so there is not need to go via properties), then group by the extracted data.

IOW, try write the LINQ like would for the SQL.